# Converting String to ISOdate in MongoDB using shell or Python Script?

Tags: python, database, mongodb

I have date in String format and Like to convert in ISOdate format in mongoshell or custom python script to achieve this. I tried all possible commands but couldn't achieve this. I like to know how to convert String date into ISOdate in mongodb.

Comment: can you post the query you've tried with sample date strings?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

- your collection name as: `youCollection`
- field name to be converted from string to date: `date`

  ```
   var records = db.youCollection.find();
   records.forEach(function(doc) {
   var dateStr = doc.date;
   if(typeof dateStr === "string")
   {
   var date = new Date(dateStr);

   db.youCollection.update({_id: doc._id}, {$set: {date: date}})
   }})
  ```

  This will convert date of `"2018-02-17T05:01:32.028Z"` format to `ISODate("2018-02-17T05:01:32.028Z")`

Answer (score 0):

I found the optimal solution for this later

Get into Database

```
use yourdatabase_name
```

Run this afterwards changing according to your requirement

```
db.YOURCOLLECION.find().forEach(function(element) {
element.DATE = new Date(element.DATE);
db.DATE.save(element);
})
```

Comment: this can break DB. try to avoid it.